# spoj ARRAYSUB: tried sliding window algorithm, not accepted

Tags: c

This is my implementation of sliding window for an O(n) solution for this problem :

http://www.spoj.com/problems/ARRAYSUB/

http://ideone.com/uwuZ0d

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i,k,n,a[1000001],q[1000001],b[1000001],m=-1;

int main() {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        if(m<a[i])
            m=a[i];
    }
    scanf("%d",&k);
    if(k==1){
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }else 
    if(k==n){
        printf("%d",m);
    }else{
    int f=0,r=0; //front, rear
    q[r++]=a[0]; //queue
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(q[f]<=a[i]){
            q[f]=a[i]; //push to front, queue with single element
            r=f+1;
        }else{
            q[r++]=a[i]; //push to rear
        }
        if(i>=k-1){
            b[i-k+1]=q[f]; //write q[f] to answer array
            if(r-f==k){ //if size of queue = k, pop first element of queue
                f++;    
            }
            while(q[f]<q[f+1] && f+1<r){  //after removal of first elementmove front till q[f]<q[f+1] 
                f++;            //i m not sure about this, but i tried many testcases, this works
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-k;i++){
            printf("%d ",b[i]);
        }
        printf("%d",b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I could not find any testcase, it wont run on, spoj just does not accept it :(

The code is well commented.

If anyone can point out some testcases or, point out the error, I would be really glad!!!

Thanks!

Comment: a) Decide for one language. b) Doesn´t Spoj give some reason why it is not accepted? c) Even better than comments would be proper indentation.

Comment: I agree--you are either dealing with C or with C++. They are radically different, so pick just one. Your code looks to me like C code.

Comment: You guys are sure harsh for me putting a C++ tag in there, sorry didnt realize the inconvenience :p

Comment: downvotes were expected :D

Comment: proper indentation ???? @deviantfan, can u plz tell me whats not indented in here !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended invariant of your cycle is as follows: the front element `q[f]` of the queue `q[f...r]` should be the *maximum* element of the queue, while the rest of queue elements can be stored in any order. Your update of `f` here

```
while(q[f]<q[f+1] && f+1<r){
  f++;
}
```

does not maintain that invariant. It finds the first *local* maximum in `q[f...r]`, while the invariant requires a *global* maximum.

Because of that problem input sequence

```
5  3  2  4  1  4  4  2  5
```

produces incorrect result. For `k = 4` it produces

```
5 3 4 4 4 5
```

while the proper output is

```
5 4 4 4 4 5
```